# Open SSL Encrypt PHP

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying to use PHP's `openssl_encrypt()` function but my key is coded in hexadecimal and the function is returning an error.  When using the `hex2bin()` function to convert the key to binary, the return value is garbled ASCII text.   Then when inserted into `openssl_encrypt()`. I get an error.

```
define('TEX_ENCRYPTION_KEY', 'hexadecimalkey...');
define('TEX_ENCRYPTION_IV', 'hexadecimalkey...');

$key = hex2bin(TEX_ENCRYPTION_KEY);
$iv = hex2bin(TEX_ENCRYPTION_IV);

$transData = '<Detail>blah blah blah</Detail>';
$alg = 'aes-256-cbc';

$encryptedData = openssl_encrypt(
    $transData,
    $alg,
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,$iv
);
```

This outputs an error:

```
error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data 
not multiple of block length
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Which algorithm are you using? please show the call to openssl encrypt.

Comment: You can't type binary code, this is not the real value. Save the binary data into a file and read from it, an ASCII string is not a binary value sy���c%�Tka�]1�k���p+$����I���

Comment: Actually it is using bin2hex(), they aren't typed in

Comment: http://php.net say: IV and Key parameteres passed to openssl command line must be in hex representation of string. Why are you convert the value to Binary?

Comment: @esdebon where does it say that? All examples show e.g. IV as `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);` This generates a string of binary data.

Comment: but openssl_encrypt function use only strings      string openssl_encrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $password [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" ]] ), then you need convert the binary to Hex no hex to binary

Comment: A "string" does not imply a human readable series of ASCII characters.

Comment: the code interpreter read human redeable strings (HEX, Base64....) characters like ��� is nothing for the interpreter in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php), there's a pretty good explanation of what the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` option does [in the comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#117208). By default, OpenSSL will pad your plaintext to a multiple of the cipher block size (16 bytes in the case of AES-256-CBC.) However, you've disabled that mechanism and OpenSSL is expecting you to ensure the length of your data is a multiple of 16. It's not, so you get the error message "data not multiple of block length."

Solution: pad your data or remove that option!

```
<?php
$transData = '<Detail>blah blah blah</Detail>';
$transData = str_pad(
    $transData,
    strlen($transData) + (16 - (strlen($transData) % 16)),
    chr(0)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

After dancing with the [openssl documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) I had the solution to replace depreciated Mcrypt function with openssl (openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt functions) and return ASCII text with base64_encode():

```
//Return encrypted string
public function stringEncrypt ($plainText, $cryptKey = '7R7zX2Urc7qvjhkr') {

  $length   = 8;
  $cstrong  = true;
  $cipher   = 'aes-128-cbc';

  if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
  {
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt(
      $plainText, $cipher, $cryptKey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $cryptKey, $as_binary=true);
    $encodedText = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
  }

  return $encodedText;
}


//Return decrypted string
public function stringDecrypt ($encodedText, $cryptKey = '7R7zX2Urc7qvjhkr') {

  $c = base64_decode($encodedText);
  $cipher   = 'aes-128-cbc';

  if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
  {
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
    $ivlenSha2len = $ivlen+$sha2len;
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
    $plainText = openssl_decrypt(
      $ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $cryptKey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
  }

  return $plainText;
}
```